# how could I create an array of the last marked value from an index array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-xarray

I'm kind of new to python and not really used to a lot of the syntax yet. I would like to know how to get an array of the last value that has been marked as a 1 from an index array. For example for

```
idx = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

values = [23, 45, 78, 37, 15, 172, 45, 8, 16, 99, 55]
```

The desired array would look like

```
[23, 23, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 8, 16, 16, 55]
```

The sample code I'm working with uses xarray to create the index array, so maybe it could also be used to get the final array. Thanks for any help or suggestions

Edit: the length of both arrays will be the same, and if the index array starts with a 0, the output should be 0 until there is a 1 in the idx array

Comment: is length of both array is same, and the array where 1,0 mention first index wiill be 1 always?

Comment: Please use typed, named and copyable examples and include the necessary imports. Please add additional requirements to the question not in a comment.

Comment: the sample code uses `xarray.where(arrayA > arrayB, 1, 0)` to create the index array. xarray doesn't have to be used for the solution, but not sure if it could be

Comment: If you had included the expected code to produce example xarrays, maybe you would've gotten xarray answers... (which I'd hope would be shorter and faster, and which I'd find more interesting).

Comment: Please clarify the type of the data. With `xarray.DataArray` for all requirements: `(values * flags.where(flags)).ffill('dim_0').fillna(0).astype('int')`. Without knowing the type and the desired output type a solution might not work.

Comment: ahh  okay, I started using python pretty recently and didn't know xarrays are a different type

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny What do you mean with second requirement?

Answer (score 2):

You could use list comprehension with an assignment expression:

```
flags = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
values = [23, 45, 78, 37, 15, 172, 45, 8, 16, 99, 55]

prev = 0
result = [(prev := value) if flag else prev 
          for value, flag in zip(values, flags)]

print(result)  # [23, 23, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37, 8, 16, 16, 55]
```

Comment: Would be slightly [faster](https://tio.run/##pVFBbsMgELzzirnZVByMXddJJL8kiiq3XadINkYYR2o/77JQRbn01BUSw8wyswL3FT4X2xyc3/eVwubQoygKMU7DdY34rBWqtO4g43zUF3Ebpo1Sa90oPLcK3UGh6aIYse7qTEZOvygcjwptexGcId6XD9K/gc7TLcJKeFq3KbAfU6c@@cOM4JFA00pIvePikTSVBGPxbVyZp0nUKh9i6r9jyocc@a@g0S8zgpnJBJjZLT7Ak6MhCPZ45at@sFcqG3kSiMU0T8dKegyVtjqrXDzhbGyZfUpWFdJHKdhtfiPf64pLyvsd540NZcATNDWZzpTc9x8) and I think clearer if you updated the variable only at true flags. I.e., put parentheses around `prev:=value`.

Comment: Updated, Kelly. Thanks.

Comment: Before `python3.8` (for the google colab users): `result = [0]; result += (v if f else result[-1] for v,f in zip(values, flags)); result[1:]`

Answer (score 1):

Let's call them arrayA and arrayB. And output array as arrayC. The algorithm would look like:

```
    check_index = 0
    for each_index in range(len(arrayA)):
      if arrayA[each_index] == 1:
        append(arrayC, arrayB[check_index])
        # this bumps the index to the next value
        check_index += 1
    
      else:
        append(arrayC, arrayB[check_index])
        # otherwise, the index would stay the same
```

Answer (score 1):

A good use case for an assignment expression (aka walrus operator):

```
index = [1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1]

arr = [23,45,78,37,15,172,45,8,16,99,55]

result = []
last = 0

for x, i in zip(arr, index):
    result.append(last := x if i else last)
```

Answer (score 1):

You *could* do this in xarray, something along these lines:

```py
import numpy as np, xarray as xr
mask = xr.DataArray([1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], dims=['x'])
values = xr.DataArray([23, 45, 78, 37, 15, 172, 45, 8, 16, 99, 55], dims=['x'])

index = xr.DataArray(np.arange(len(mask)), dims=['x']).where(mask).ffill('x').astype(int)
```

You could then use this index to select positionally from values:

```py
In [3]: index
Out[3]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 11)>
array([ 0,  0,  0,  3,  3,  3,  3,  7,  8,  8, 10])
Dimensions without coordinates: x

In [4]: values.isel(x=index)
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray (x: 11)>
array([23, 23, 23, 37, 37, 37, 37,  8, 16, 16, 55])
Dimensions without coordinates: x
```

For something of this size, the list comprehension is much simpler and faster though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple `list comprehension` to filter the data. Below `ln` will equal the last `dat` with a matching 1 `cmp`.

```
cmp = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
dat = [23, 45, 78, 37, 15, 172, 45, 8, 16, 99, 55]

ln=0
print([ln:=d if c else ln for c,d in zip(cmp,dat)])
```